# How do I optimize this LINQ query? It runs localhost but it doesn't run on Azure

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have this LINQ query and am getting results I need. However it takes 5-6 seconds to show results on localhost, and I can't even run this on Azure.
I'm new to LINQ, and I'm sure that I'm doing something inefficient.
Could someone direct me to optimize?

```
var joblist = (from t in db.Tracking
               group t by t.JobNumber into j
               let id = j.Max(x => x.ScanDate)
               select new
               {
                   jn = j.Key,
                   ti = j.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ScanDate == id).TrackingId,
                   sd = j.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ScanDate == id).ScanDate,
                   lc = j.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ScanDate == id).LocationId
               }).Where(z => z.lc == lid).Where(z => z.jn != null);

 jfilter = (from tr in joblist
            join lc in db.Location on tr.lc equals lc.LocationId
            join lt in db.LocType on lc.LocationType equals lt.LocationType
            select new ScanMod
            {
                TrackingId = tr.ti,
                LocationName = lc.LocationName,
                JobNumber = tr.jn,
                LocationTypeName = lt.LocationTypeName,
                ScanDate = tr.sd,
                StoneId = ""
            }).OrderByDescending(z => z.ScanDate);
```

**UPDATE:**
This query runs on Azure(s1) but it takes 30 seconds. This table has 500,000 rows and I assume that OrderByDescending or FirstOrDefault is killing it...

```
var joblist = db.Tracking
              .GroupBy(j => j.JobNumber)
              .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(j => j.ScanDate).FirstOrDefault());

jfilter = (from tr in joblist
           join lc in db.Location on tr.LocationId equals lc.LocationId
           join lt in db.LocType on lc.LocationType equals lt.LocationType
           where tr.LocationId == lid
           select new ScanMod
           {
                TrackingId = tr.TrackingId,
                LocationName = lc.LocationName,
                JobNumber = tr.JobNumber,
                LocationTypeName = lt.LocationTypeName,
                ScanDate = tr.ScanDate,
                StoneId = ""
            }).OrderByDescending(z => z.ScanDate);
```

Comment: Can you post the entity classes involved, so we can play with the query and check the generated SQL?

Comment: public class ScanMod
    {
        public int TrackingId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string StoneId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScanDate { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public string LocationTypeName { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public partial class Tracking
    {
        public int TrackingId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string StoneId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScanDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LocationId { get; set; } 
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public partial class Location
    {
        public Location()
        {
            this.Tracking = new HashSet<Tracking>();
        }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LocationType { get; set; }
        public virtual LocType LocType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tracking> Tracking { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public partial class LocType
    {
        public LocType()
        {
            this.Location = new HashSet<Location>();
        }
        public int LocationType { get; set; }
        public string LocationTypeName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Location { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I  think this is all.

Comment: Thank you. The original query is not good. The updated query is fine, I've played with it and can't see how to further improve it. You might try adding index for `JobNumber` and/or `ScanDate` columns in the `Tracking` table.

Comment: I guess I need to scale up Azure SQL... It's so odd that storage limit is 250GB and my data is only 30MB, yet having problem sorting half million rows of data. Azure SQL is so slow...